# Django password_change view raising NoReverseMatch exception

Tags: python, django

```
app_name = "myadmin"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^change-password/$', auth_views.password_change,
        { 'template_name': 'myadmin/password_change',  'current_app': 'myadmin',  },
        name='password_reset'
        ),

    url(r'^password-change-done/$', auth_views.password_change_done,
        {'current_app': 'myadmin'},
        name='password_change_done'
        ),
]
```

When I visit `127.0.01:8001/myadmin/change-password` it raises the follow error:

> `NoReverseMatch` at `/myadmin/change-password/` Reverse for
>   `'password_change_done'` with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

As you can see I am already passing `app_name` to `password_change()` view but It is not reaching inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

You're namespacing your `myadmin` app. Thus, you should use

```
reverse('myadmin:password_change_done')
```

More on namespacing [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls).

Comment: This is bad if I update the project, the whole application will break and I have to do it again.

If this bad specially when other apps are using `password_change_done` view too.

Comment: Is there any way to pass app name to this view using from `url()` ?